# Unity - Game not running on android 8 and 9

Tags: unity

Game  is crashing with message "app has stoped" when i am opening it (it doesnt show splash screen) ,  everything is fine when I am creating new project with same unity version, build, player and sdk settings . No errors in unity and log from logcat. Any ideas?? 
Link to logcat log https://pastebin.com/yzvkB3Jv  (Game name is iPenkim)

Comment: It doesn't look like we have enough information in this question to reproduce and diagnose the problem here. Can you make this happen when starting from a new, empty Unity project? Walk us through the steps to replicate the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Is there any version of android that works? Did you check Logcat?

Comment: This game I am making about year, When I am starting from empty unity project its game is running on android 8/9 without problems, I built it on another computer and still nothing, problem in project , not in unity or pc , logcat link https://pastebin.com/yzvkB3Jv

Comment: Next, copy stuff from your project that has the problem into the new Unity project a little at a time, trying to run the result on Android 8 & 9 every so often. When the new project starts showing the error, you can be fairly confident the last thing you added to it is related to causing the error, giving you a lead in tracking it down.

Comment: I changed logcat settings and get new logs where are a line "----- beginning of crash" watch this please.  https://pastebin.com/s2p9Sc6Z

Comment: " ComponentInfo{com.iPenkim.iPenkim/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only fullscreen opaque activities can request orientation " what is this?